# Convert List<OBj1> to List<Obj2> in windows phone 8

Tags: c#

how to convert List to List in c# windows phone 8 app?

`obj_1` and `obj_2` are lists.
I have Following code:

```
List<obj_1> list = new List<obj_1>();
obj_1 = new List<obj_1>(obj_2.Of Type<obj_1>().To List());
```

OR

```
List<obj_1> list = new List<obj_1>();
obj_1 = new List<obj_1>(obj_2.Cast<obj_1>().To List());
```

while debugging the code, count in obj_1 is 0 and obj_2 is 10.Please suggest any solution.Thank You

Comment: Is there any hierarchical relationship between the two types `obj_1` and `obj_2`?

Comment: No there is no Hierarchical Relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert from **List<> of type obj1** to **List<> of type obj2** then [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx)

```
 List<obj2>  resultList= List<obj1>.ConvertAll(x => new Obj2 { Property = x.SomeValue });
```

or

```
List<obj_2> resultList = new List<obj_2>(List<obj_1>.Cast<obj_1>());
```

Comment: Your code sample isn't using the `ConvertAll` method though.